# Cookies saved in Postman but not in browser from react-frontend with MERN-Stack

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, nginx, cookies, rtk-query

Hello i have big problems to get my React(with RTK-Query) connect to my Backend-API (Node, express, nginx). Supringsly when i use my API with Postman everything is working (i can login, i can change data and so on, as long as i dont delete my Token in the Cookie in Postman).

My backend is hosted on a EC2-Server and the server has the following configuration:

Nginx:

[image]

Node Server:

```
import "express-async-errors";
import express from "express";
import cookieParser from "cookie-parser";

const app = express();
import dotenv from "dotenv";
dotenv.config();

import { dirname } from "path";
import { fileURLToPath } from "url";
import path from "path";

import helmet from "helmet";
import xss from "xss-clean";
import mongoSanitaze from "express-mongo-sanitize";
import rateLimit from "express-rate-limit";
import cors from "cors";

// rateLimitconfig
const limiter = rateLimit({
  windowMs: 10 * 60 * 1000, // 10 minutes
  max: 200, // Limit each IP to 200 requests per `window` (here, per 15 minutes)
  standardHeaders: true, // Return rate limit info in the `RateLimit-*` headers
  legacyHeaders: false, // Disable the `X-RateLimit-*` headers
  message:
    "too many requests from this IP adress, please try again after 10 minutes",
});

// const __dirname = dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url));
// only when for deployment
// app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, "./client/build")));

//database and authenticateUser
import connectDB from "./db/connect.js";

// routers
import authRouter from "./routes/authRoutes.js";
import taskRouter from "./routes/tasksRoutes.js";
import diaryRouter from "./routes/diaryRoutes.js";

//middleware
import notFoundMiddleware from "./middleware/notFound.js";
import errorHandlerMiddleware from "./middleware/errorHandler.js";
import morgan from "morgan";
import authenticateUser from "./middleware/auth.js";

//activate morgan

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production") {
  app.use(morgan("dev"));
}

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(helmet());
app.use(xss());
app.use(mongoSanitaze());
app.use(limiter);

app.use(cookieParser());

app.use("/api/v1/auth", authRouter);
app.use("/api/v1/tasks", authenticateUser, taskRouter);
app.use("/api/v1/diary", authenticateUser, diaryRouter);

// app.get("*", (req, res) => {
//   res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "./client/build", "index.html"));
// });
app.use(notFoundMiddleware);
app.use(errorHandlerMiddleware);

const port = process.env.PORT || 7000;

const start = async () => {
  try {
    await connectDB(process.env.MONGO_URL);
    app.listen(port, () => {
      console.log(`Server is listening on port ${port}...`);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
console.log("hey ho");
start();
```

Login Controller:

```
const login = async (req, res) => {
  ....


  const JWTToken = user.JWTCreate();

  attachCookies({ res, cookieContent: JWTToken });
  res.status(StatusCodes.OK).json({
    userData: {
      name: user.name,
      email: user.email,
    },
  });
};
```

Content of the attachCookies.js

```
const attachCookies = ({ res, cookieContent }) => {
      res.cookie("JWTToken", cookieContent, {
        httpOnly: true,
        expires: new Date(Date.now() + 8 * 3600000),
        secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production",
      });
    };
    
export default attachCookies;
```

My frontend deals with the API with RTK-Query with the following code:

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react";

export const apiSlice = createApi({
  reducerPath: "api",
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: "http://api.xyz.com/api/v1" }),
  tagTypes: ["Tasks", "Diary", "Logout"],
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    // USER API
   
   .....
    loginUser: builder.mutation({
      query: (initialUser) => ({
        url: "/auth/login",
        method: "POST",
        body: initialUser,
      }),
    }),
   ....



});
```

When i run the my React-App locally and try to login, in the browser it shows me the login was successful (StatusCode: 200) and in the body of the response is the  correct content. So the communication with the server works. It even shows me, that the server is sending the correct cookie (with mit JsonWebToken) in the response.

BUT in browser i cant find the cookie in the Web-Storage of the browser (i tried with mozilla and chrome).

A little time ago i uploaded Frontend-and-Backend on the same server on EC2 and everything was working (so maybe the problem are the different domains, but why is Postman working?). But people told me that its best practice to use the S3 and Cloudfront for frontend and run only the backend on EC2. So i am trying to get it running. When i try to connect from my frontend on S3 to the backend then the login request even give not any StatusCode and only says "mixed block".

I tried several things:

Access-Control-Allow-Origin in the nginx config

Access-Control-Allow-Methods in the nginx config

credentials: "include" in the RTK-Query of the API.

HttpOnly: "false" in the attachCookies

SameSite: "lax" in the attachCookies

But nothing worked. For me the big problem is, why its not saving the cookies from the server? And why its working in Postman and neither from localhost, nor the frontend running in S3?

I am a bit desperated and would be very happy for any advice or hint.

Comment: where you able to solve the issue? I m having similar issue

Answer (score 0):

Is your .env on your ec2 instance? My registration controller requires a secret from my .env and I would always forget to create my .env on the server